# Will custom Lambda layer be included in the backpropagating in Keras

Tags: keras

So lets suppose I have the following lambda layer:

l = Lambda(lambda x: 1/(1+math.e**x))

This is a sigmoid function. Now since I didn't specify the derivative of this function anywhere I am curious whether it will be included in the back-propagation or not. Is there some magical automatic mechanism which does that for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will be included in the back-propagation. However, there is no magic. Theano will define a computational graph that has pre-defined derivatives of many basic operations. As long as you can use those basic expressions to define your function, you do not have to worry about back-propagation.

In your case, forward pass can be built by first computing `exp(x)`, then `1 + exp(x)` and finally `1/(1 + exp(x))`. Note that every step builds on the previous step. The same is true for the backward pass as follows.

In your backward pass, you have three operations. Firstly, derivative of `1/Z (Z = 1 + exp(x))`, then derivative of `1 + Y (Y = exp(x))` and finally derivative of `exp(x)`.

It is quite easy for Theano to build a computation graph for these three operations. Now if you have a function, say `1/(1 + f(x))`, where Theano neither knows derivative of `f(x)` nor it can be decomposed into a set of basic expressions, then you will have to define its gradient manually by modifying Theano source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more thing. You mentioned that I will need to define the derivative of f(x). What if I don't? will I get some error or f(x) will simply be excluded from backprop?

Comment: I think you will get an error. Just to clarify, you do not have to define any new derivative as that of `exp(x)` is pre-defined.